# Custom list with related numbering

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I want to have a list which looks like something produced by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={Aim (\alph*)}]
\item\label{item:this} Do this.
\item\label{item:that} Do that.
\item\label{item:these} Do these.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

So it will look something like:

> Aim (a) Do this.
>
> Aim (b) Do that.
>
> Aim (c) Do these.

So this clearly lists my aims. However, I want to reference the numbering *without* the word "Aim". For example, I want

```
I will achieve Aims \ref{item:this}--\ref{item:these}.
```

to render as

> "I will achieve Aims (a)-(c)."

Currently, it renders as

> "I will achieve Aims Aims (a)-Aims (c)."

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `enumitem` package allows for the `ref` option in order to change the cross-reference format deviating from the `label` content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

I will achieve Aims \ref{item:this} -- \ref{item:these}.

\begin{enumerate}[label={Aim (\alph*)},ref={(\alph*)}]
\item\label{item:this} Do this.
\item\label{item:that} Do that.
\item\label{item:these} Do these.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Providing a special list 'aims':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

I will achieve Aims \ref{item:this} -- \ref{item:these}.

\newlist{aims}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[aims,1]{label={Aim (\alph*)},ref={(\alph*)}}


\begin{aims}
\item\label{item:this} Do this.
\item\label{item:that} Do that.
\item\label{item:these} Do these.
\end{aims}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: With `cleveref` it is possible to compress the reference range

Comment: Thanks. This works almost-perfectly. "Almost", because is there anyway to avoid careless errors, introduced when editing late at night, like "...[label={Objective \arabic*}, ref={\alph*}]..."?

Comment: @user1729: I don't understand what you mean... Why would you want to use arabic numbers and then refer to it with `\alph*` style?

Comment: That's my point - its an error introduced because I have to change to things but only changed one. Is there a way to link these two so that I only have to change one thing? (If there is no easy way then I am happy to leave it with two things to change.)

Comment: @user1729: It's another question, that's the first issue then... and perhaps defining a new list with `\newlist` would be the best option in order to change things in just one place

Comment: Okay, thanks. Its a minor point so I'll figure it out myself. [Also, I saw that you rejected my removing of the "twocolumn" from your answer - I had also removed it from my question as it crept in in copy-and-paste but was not neccessary. So I figured removing it from your answer would reduce confusion.]

Comment: @user1729: I'll change my answers preferably myself ;-)

Comment: @user1729: I'll added a new list named `aims`, because changing `enumerate` globally is not the best strategy...

Answer (score 1):

You could define a dedicated list environment, `aims`, and use `cleveref`, to save some typing:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newlist{aims}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[aims, 1]{label = Aim (\alph*) , ref = (\alph*) }
\crefname{aimsi}{aim}{aims}
\creflabelformat{aimsi}{#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{aims}
\item\label{aim:this} Do this.
\item\label{aim:that} Do that.
\item\label{aim:these} Do these.
\end{aims}
\Cref{aim:this}--\cref{aim:these} will be achieved, or \cref{aim:this,aim:that,aim:these}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've mentioned `aims` list already and cleveref ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Sorry, I didn't see it. I guess it was not in your initial post, and I was lovingly polishing my answer. Of course, I'll remove mine, since it brings nothing more.

Comment: No, I've upvoted it already ;-)

Comment: Let's say it's for the demo of the use of `\cref`, in this case ;o)

Comment: Mais oui! Bien sûr!